# Is it possible to listen to an inactivity event in socket.io?

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io

Compared to using websockets directly, [socket.io handles heartbeat events and automatic reconnection](https://socket.io/docs/v4/#automatic-reconnection). However, as my client is very time sensitive, I also want to display a warning message when the socket has been inactive for N seconds, and remove the warning when a new message / heartbeat comes in.

Is it possible to create event listeners for such "active" / "inactive" events on socket.io? Or would it be easier to use plain websockets and implement the heartbeat / reconnection mechanism by hand?

Comment: You can measure time from the last event sent

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having a `setTimeout` variable in the socket that will emit a message to user in case of inactivity, and reset the timeout after receiving the message.

Something along the lines of:

```
io.on('connection', async (socket) => {
  let userTimeout = setTimeout(() => socket.to(socket.id).emit("You have been inactive"), 60000);

  /* ... */

  socket.on('message', async(socket) => {
    if(userTimeout) clearTimeout(userTimeout);
    userTimeout = setTimeout(() => socket.to(socket.id).emit("You have been inactive"), 60000);
  })
})
```